# Certbot certificate rate limit hit during automation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate, subdomain, certbot

I have purchased some **elastic ips** from aws which are mapped against some **sub-domains**.

e.g      **elastic ip** mapped against **xyz.domain.com**.

I have an algorithm which creates **ec2 Instances** as per load on our website.
After successful start of that instance i associate that **elastic ip** to new **instance** using api.

it initiates my service to generate **certificate** using `certbot`, which makes my new **instance** setting complete and now i can use it in my existing **architecture**.

When load again goes back to normal i remove those new instances.

My problem is when load is fluctuating i sometimes hit `rate limits` in `certbot` e.g. and unable to function properly because without **ssl certificate** my whole system seems to collapse.

So what can i do to solve this problem?

Fixed parameters are -

1. 10 elastic ips.  All the domains are subdomain of a main domain
   which are already mapped to elastic ips.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use certbot then you need to store these certificates and reuse them when you start a new instance. You can use a parameter store securestring for example for each elasic IP and when you spin up the instance it checks this parameter first. If there is no certificate or it expires soon then get a new cert and overwrite the stored one. With this solution, a new instance does not mean a new certificate.

But this setup feels wrong. You can use the Application Load Balancer that integrates with ACM and Route53 so you can move the HTTPS termination to a single service then don't care about how instances are starting/stopping in the background.